# How do I "Declare the scalar variable" in a VIEW in Sql Server (2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I´m trying to create a **VIEW** in **SQL Server** 2005.

The SQL code is working as such (I´m using it in VS2008), but in SQL Server I´m unable to save it, as error message "Declare the scalar variable @StartDate" and "Declare the scalar variable @EndDate" pops up.

Here is the code:

```
WITH Calendar AS (SELECT     CAST(@StartDate AS datetime) AS Date
     UNION ALL
     SELECT     DATEADD(d, 1, Date) AS Expr1
     FROM         Calendar AS Calendar_1
     WHERE     (DATEADD(d, 1, Date) < @EndDate))
    SELECT     C.Date, C2.Country, COALESCE (SUM(R.[Amount of people per day needed]), 0) AS [Allocated testers]
     FROM         Calendar AS C CROSS JOIN
                            dbo.Country AS C2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            dbo.Requests AS R ON C.Date BETWEEN R.[Start date] AND R.[End date] AND R.CountryID = C2.CountryID
     GROUP BY C.Date, C2.Country
```

And **my question is of course - exactly how should I declare them?**

I tried to put the following first in the code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate smalldatetime
DECLARE @EndDate smalldatetime
```

But that didn´t do the trick, just as I expected - it only gave me another pop-up message:

"The Declare cursor SQL construct or statement is not supported."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Alex K has mentioned, you should write it as a inline table valued function. Here is the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175924(SQL.80).aspx) that describes about it.

In short, syntax would be something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetForPeriod
    ( @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime) 
RETURNS TABLE 
RETURN 
   SELECT  [[ your column list ]]
   FROM    [[ table list]
   WHERE   [[some column] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

You can have one select query (however complex, can use CTE). And then you will use it as

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetForPeriod('1-Jan-2010', '31-Jan-2010')
```

Comment: Nice, gonna test that out - I see it as an acceptable answer :-)

Comment: Downside of functions is that they are very poorly performing if you want to join or filter on it.

Comment: @IanBoyd, what you say is generally true for multi-statement TVF and scalar functions. However, the solution here uses inline table valued function. AFAIK, SQL Server would expand the UDF in the query (just as done in the view). Hence, contrary to what you have stated, they would work a lot better in join/filter (assuming participating tables has appropriate indices) or at least, there shouldn't be any penalty involved (other than extra parsing) for using inline TVF. See see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/10/28/query-performance-and-multi-statement-table-valued-functions.aspx

Comment: Would there be a further benefit from adding WITH SCHEMABINDING?

Comment: @Mark, `WITH SCHEMABINDING` is always beneficial due to associated dependency checks (i.e. avoiding breaking UDF due to schema changes). But if you are asking from performance perspective, there is no benefit - that applies to scalar functions (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/12/596424.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If by **VIEW** you mean an SQL Server native view (`CREATE VIEW ...`) then you cannot use local variables at all (you would use a table-valued udf instead).

If you mean something else, then adding `DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME` makes that statement parse fine, is it the entirety of the SQL?

Comment: I mean that I in the SQL Server Management Studio right clicks on the "Views" folder and selects "New View..." - I´ve created other views this way, and then I use them in Visual Studio 2008 (C#) to use them when creating "TableAdapters", for example. Well, what is a table-valued udf? Where and how do I create it, do you know?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample query that uses CTE to nicely emulate internal variable construction. You can test-run it in your version of SQL Server.

```
CREATE VIEW vwImportant_Users AS
WITH params AS (
    SELECT 
    varType='%Admin%', 
    varMinStatus=1)
SELECT status, name 
    FROM sys.sysusers, params
    WHERE status > varMinStatus OR name LIKE varType

SELECT * FROM vwImportant_Users
```

yielding output:

```
status  name
12      dbo
0       db_accessadmin
0       db_securityadmin
0       db_ddladmin
```

also via `JOIN`

```
WITH params AS ( SELECT varType='%Admin%', varMinStatus=1)
SELECT status, name 
    FROM sys.sysusers INNER JOIN params ON 1=1
    WHERE status > varMinStatus OR name LIKE varType
```

also via `CROSS APPLY`

```
WITH params AS ( SELECT varType='%Admin%', varMinStatus=1)
SELECT status, name 
    FROM sys.sysusers CROSS APPLY params
    WHERE status > varMinStatus OR name LIKE varType
```

Answer (score -1):

try replacing all your @X, @Y with A.X and A.Y, add to your code:
FROM (SELECT X = 'literalX', Y = 'literalY') A
then you have put all your literals in one spot and have only one copy of them.