# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using this SQL code:

```
DECLARE
@vals AS varchar(MAX),
@q  AS varchar(MAX)

select @vals = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(chgnum) 
        from pppview_nl
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @q = 'SELECT lotdetid,' + @vals + ' FROM 
                        (
                SELECT TOP 50 lotdetid, LineValue as val,chgnum FROM pppview_nl ORDER BY lotdetid DESC
                        ) a
                        pivot 
                        (
                            max(val)
                            for chgnum in (' + @vals + ')
                        ) b'
execute(@q)
```

Which works fine, and changes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPd9a.png

INTO:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDOgI.png

It runs fine on Navicat and SQL Fiddle, but when I try and save it,
I get this issue:
[SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'

I've done quite a bit of reading and far from redoing the entire thing, how can this issue be fixed? I read something somewhere about needing to but all declares inside a ~~whatever it was~~ but then other people are seeming saying it doesn't make a difference.

Hope someone can assist me in this, as it's a bit of a head-scratcher how it works fine but doesn't save.

Regards, Oscar.

---

**Edit:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[o_getvals]
    @lotdetit varchar(6)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @vals AS varchar(MAX),
    @q  AS varchar(MAX)
    select @vals = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(chgnum) 
            from pppview_nl
            ORDER BY chgnum desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'')

    set @q = 'SELECT lotdetid,' + @vals + ' FROM 
                            (
                                    SELECT TOP 50 lotdetid, LineValue as val,chgnum FROM pppview_nl WHERE lotdetid = ' + @lotdetit + ' ORDER BY lotdetid DESC
                            ) a
                            pivot 
                            (
                                max(val)
                                for chgnum in (' + @vals + ')
                            ) b'
    execute(@q)
END
```

Stored proceedure did the trick, thanks jyparask and everyone else. :)

Comment: what do you mean by "when I try and save it"? Saving it as a stored procedure, view?

Comment: I'm totally not sure. But shouldn't your declare and with a delimiter  (eg `;`) just before you start your select ?

Comment: You need to create a stored procedure. I don't think a VIEW can handle this.

Comment: You can't do this in a `view`

Comment: Local variables are not allowed in a VIEW. You may read [SQL Views - no variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114826/sql-views-no-variables) and [How do I “Declare the scalar variable” in a VIEW in Sql Server (2005)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475712/how-do-i-declare-the-scalar-variable-in-a-view-in-sql-server-2005).

Comment: Views have to have a "shape" that is fixed - the number and type of columns, together with their names. Your query produces a variable number of columns, so it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this piece of work you should create a `stored procedure`.

Comment: table-valued can't use `exec` either.

Answer (score 0):

I cam across this issue 'invalid syntax near'.  After a brief investigation I discovered that it's due to conflict between by Function declaration parameters and the use of the parameters in my query i.e. declaring int variables as varchar in my Function signature.

Let me know if this solves the problem.......